# Automatically reconnect Wi-Fi connection and captive portal

Tags: windows, wifi

I'm looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows that can automatically reconnect to the Wi-Fi network and captive portal whenever the Wi-Fi get disconnected (this happens approximately every 24 hours on my company network).

Any price and license is fine.

Comment: Why is it happening? Is it one of those "you were inactive, so I am dropping you" things? Back in the "free dial-up" days, there were programs which would ping at regular intervals, to provide some traffic. Might that help?

Comment: @Mawg the Wi-Fi network has a policy to disconnect any client that has been connected for over 24 hours, so having traffic doesn't prevent disconnections.

Comment: Can you convince IT, or your manager, that you have a valid need? Or is it just a convenience thing? And doesn't Windows wifi have a "connect automatically" checkbox?

Comment: @Mawg "Can you convince IT, or your manager, that you have a valid need?" -> IT folks refused to make any exception.

Comment: @Mawg  "doesn't Windows wifi have a "connect automatically" checkbox?" -> it does, but for some reason I have to manually disconnect from the Wi-Fi network and then connect to the Wi-Fi network again (+ web authenticate myself on the captive portal), for the connection to work.

Comment: Then I guess my search for a workaround won't hack it; you really do need an app  - and, I don't know of one, and you can Google as well as I. Given your rep on S.O, I would suggest a Python script (of course, if you do find something, please post it here, in order to help others in future)